# Azure cognitive document translation UI recommendations

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, translation, microsoft-translator

Hoping someone can help or push me in the right direction with a requirement a client has requested.

My client works in a secure restricted environment where external translation services are blocked or prohibited.

Currently using a paid Azure translator cognitive services subscription with S1 plan of blob storage. I have created 'source' and 'target' containers, generated SAS keys and followed a online tutorial with a basic C# code. If I upload a document to be translated via Azure storage explorer into the 'source' container, run the C# code via VS code this will translate the document and place into the 'target' container which can be downloaded.

My question is what is the easiest and fastest way to make this user friendly?

I am not a developer although do have a basic grasp on API and a little python but  developing something like this is far beyond my skillsets.

Any suggestions or recommendations would be greatly apricated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/DocumentTranslation
has an application that performs all the necessary document translation tasks. Provided as source and as compiled binary.

Command line for Windows, Linux, MacOS

```
doctr translate <source folder OR document> [<target folder>] --to <language code>
```

Graphical User Interface for Windows

[image: GUI]

Comment: Thanks Chris, will take a look at this.

Comment: You can use the Github "Issues" function to report any bugs, problems, wishes, requests with the app.